# How can IntRange object have access to Iterator function e.g. forEach?

Tags: kotlin

I dive into the `IntRange` class declaration as below

```
public class IntRange(start: Int, endInclusive: Int) : IntProgression(start, endInclusive, 1), ClosedRange<Int>
```

Both  `IntProgression` and `ClosedRange` doesn't seems to implement `Iterator` interface.

So it surprise my that `IntRange` object could have access to `Iterator` function like `forEach`. How could that magically happen?

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no magic here. `IntRange` is a subclass of `IntProgression`, which [implements the Iterable interface](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-progression/index.html). You can see the source code of the implementation [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/src/kotlin/Progressions.kt#L95).

Comment: Nice, thanks! It blinded as the implementation is done several lines below.

Answer (score 1):

> Both IntProgression and ClosedRange doesn't seems to implement Iterator interface.

Because the `forEach` function is on `Iterable`, they need to implement `Iterable`, and `IntProgression` does:

```
open class IntProgression : Iterable<Int>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! It blinded as the implementation is done several lines below.